# Copy files from GoPro over USB on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, gopro, gvfs

I'm having a problem to copy files from GoPro over standard USB connection. 
I can copy tons of photos without any problem, but the connections break when I copy large (800Mb+) video files.

In my system (Ubuntu 14.10), the GoPro is mounted using gvfs as: gphoto2://[usb:003,018]

I guess gvfs is causing problems. gvfs-move also fails:

```
gvfs-move "gphoto2://[usb:003,028]/GOPR0396.MP4" gopro/
...
progress 562814208/1990950259
Error moving file gphoto2://[usb:003,028]/GOPR0396.MP4: Error getting file: -1: Unspecified error
```

Do you know of any workaround to mount is as standard USB external drive?

When I use microSD card from GoPro in my Ubuntu laptop with card reader, everything copies without any problem.

BTW: I was not completely sure where to ask this question, but finally I have decided to post it here.

**EDIT**
rsync seems to work, but it's rather slow (15Mb/s) for USB3 and microSDHC:

```
rsync -av --progress /run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto2\:host\=%5Busb%3A003%2C048%5D/ gopro/
sent 13,581,365,605 bytes  received 114 bytes  15,691,930.35 bytes/sec
```

**EDIT2**
The problem is absent in Ubuntu 14.04 - shotwell manages importing just fine.

Comment: Is the cable perfectly stable? This might happen when due to some movement.

Comment: yes, it's perfectly stable.

Comment: I can also confirm this, for the download does not even start...

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to skip using usb altogether and downloading the files using the integrated wifi hotspot and http server. This is the way I do it because is faster then using mtp.

1. To avoid making the unit shutdown itself after few seconds open the gopro app and go to the camera menu and then browse the files
2. open http://10.5.5.9:8080/videos/DCIM/ in the browser to check for the directory of interest (like 100GOPRO/)
3. retrieve them with wget -r or curl

I know this answer is not directly answering the question but offer an alternate solution that is not depending on external library

Comment: this is working even in windows. thankyou,

Answer (score 2):

I could avoid it by changing the setting in Nautilus. The issue is setting the parameter Show Thumbnails to "Never" before connecting the camera in the Preview Tab.

I hope that this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

GoPro 8:

Select ***MTP*** as connection type in the
GoPro *Preferences > Connection > **USB Connection Menu***.

This way, the GoPro is automatically mounted after plug-in of the USB cable (Linux Mint 21).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial):

1. [download the following updates from the next ubuntu verison "The Yakkety Yak"](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgphoto2/+index)

   - [libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb)
   - [libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_i386.deb)
   - [libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_i386.deb)
   - [libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb)
2. install them

   `sudo dpkg -i libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_i386.deb libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_i386.deb libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb`

You can now import videos with Shotwell.

Answer (score -2):

Install "AV-Linux", this distro will recognize your GoPro straight away and let you do whatever you want with the footage. Use Kdenlive for editing, fisheye removal etc etc.

Comment: I seriously doubt installing another distro is a viable solution.